# Improving sum() calculations on evenly spaced list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a code where I need 10Million evenly spaced number between 0 and 1 and I have a logic function which is responsible to pick a random index and **return the sum of numbers from that index till the end of the list**.

Thus the code looks like below,

```
import random
import numpy as np

ten_million = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 10000000)

def deep_dive_logic():
    # this pick is derived from good logic, however, let's just use random here for demonstration
    pick = random.randint(0, 10000000)
    return sum(ten_million[pick:])

for _ in range(2500):
  r = deep_dive_logic()
  print(r)

  # more logic ahead...
```

The problem here is as **I loop** sum() on a list of such size it takes approx. 1.3 s for each result.

[image]

**Is there any efficient way to reduce the 1.3s wait per call?** I also tried creating a kind of cache dictionary, but the deep_dive_logic() function runs in a multi-process environment hence there is need to cache this dictionary, either redis or a json.dump not a choice because of the size of dictionary mounts to around 236MB and adds up as overhead in inter-process communication if not cached.

```
sums_dict = {0: sum(ten_million)}
even_difference = (ten_million[1] - ten_million[0])

for i in range(len(ten_million) - 1):
    sums_dict[i+1] = sums_dict[i] - (even_difference * (i+1))
```

**I need help with either caching of 10Million dictionary or an alternate formula to return the result without using sum() or any out-of-box solution.**

https://repl.it/repls/HoneydewGoldenShockwave

Comment: Did you try `numpy.sum`? It might faster.

Comment: Yes, use `numpy.sum`, time goes from around 1.5s to 0.015s on my machine

Comment: you can solve this analytically

Comment: That was a good suggestion **10 loops, best of 3: 18.5 ms per loop** using numpy. Let's brainstorm more....

Comment: I don't understand your question, if they are evenly spaced, they are an [arithmetic progression with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) an explicit formula for their sum.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Can you suggest some how of the analytics part?

Comment: @MrT Yes, I am actually trying to figure out if this information can be exploited to get the results, given that we know the number at the pick_index and the length of list

Comment: You have the first, the last and the number of elements. You don't need anything else to calculate the sum.

Comment: @MrT The sum has to be calculated from the pick_index `sum(ten_million[pick:])` Sorry I didn't catch your answer though?

Comment: Have you looked at the wikipedia page MrT linked? The [formula is there](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/451ac6091a7a5a30b17a50aec671425d45e166db), right below the ["sum" heading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.sum(ten_million)` does it in about 0.005 seconds, whereas `sum(ten_million)` is about 1.5 seconds on my machine

As for a solution without using any out of the box functions, as suggested in the comments to your question by MrT, you can use the property of arithmetic progressions, which says that the sum of a progression is equal to `n(a1+an) / 2`, where `n` is the number of elements (10000000), a1 is your first element (0), and an is your last element (1). In your example, this is `10000000(0+1) / 2 = 5000000`

so, for your deep_dive_logic function, just return that:

```
def deep_dive_logic():
    pick = random.randint(0, 10000000)
    return (len(ten_million)-pick)*(ten_million[pick]+ten_million[-1]) / 2
```

Also does the job extremely fast, in fact, much faster than `np.sum`: on average, the arithmetic progression calculation took 1.223e-06 seconds, whereas `np.sum` took 0.00577 seconds on my machine. Makes sense, seeing how it's just one addition, one multiplication, and one division...

Comment: shouldn't this be `((len(ten_million) - pick) * (ten_million[pick] + ten_million[-1])) / 2` ? because n is number of elements we are going to add..

Answer (score 1):

Do it analytically:

```
def cumm_sum(start, finish, steps, k):
    step = (finish - start) / steps
    pop = (finish - k) / step
    return (pop + 1) * 0.5 * (k + finish)
```

and the call would be like:

```
pick = ten_million[random.randint(0, 10000000)]
result = cumm_sum(0.0, 1.0, 10000000, pick)
```

Comment: I am not sure this returns valid answer `cumm_sum(0.0, 1.0, 10000000, ten_million[5000])  = 4999999.250249749` but `sum(ten_million[5000:]) = 4999998.750249899`

Comment: `step` introduces an unnecessary float point error. Print out `pop` to see, what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

1. use math to reduce the problem complexity:

   The sum of an arithmetic progression is given by

   ```
   (m+n)*(m-n+1)*0.5
   ```
2. use np.vectorize to speed up the array operation:

   ```
   ten_m = 10000000

   def sum10m_py(n):
       return (1+n)*(ten_m-n*ten_m+1)*0.5

   sum_np = np.vectorize(sum_py)
   ```
3. pick the elements you want, and then apply the vectorized function on it.

   ```
   mask = np.random.randint(0,ten_m,2500)

   sums = sum_np(ten_million[mask])
   ```

Comment: This returns `sum_np(ten_million[[5000]]) = 2.49875050e+17` but  `sum(ten_million[5000:]) = 4999998.750249899`

Comment: thanks for that, fixed the bug in the function `sum10m_py`